# How to grep all files in directory for "$_POST" or "$_GET" and "include"

Tags: php, linux, grep

I want to have a grep that has one or more from each of the following groups.

"include,include_once,exec"

AND

"$_GET, $_POST"

So the file must have one or more from BOTH groups. (checking a whole directory of php files)

I'm trying to scan some PHP files for vulnerabilities but I really suck at grep :(

Comment: you don't have local copies of your files?

Comment: If you show the code you are trying to use and the error that the code produces, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I have no code - I'm just trying to do the grep (I have NO idea what I'm doing in grep)

Comment: well most editors search functions should be adequate.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easy enough to do the searches individualy, so start with fgrep -r "\$_GET" *.php and then carry on with the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting simple with commands like:

```
grep --color=auto -ER '\$_POST|\$_GET' .
```

or

```
grep --color=auto -ER 'include(_once)+|exec\(|require(_once)+' .
```

The above commands will color the found patterns in the output. Notice the regular expressions (enabled via -E) and the recursive search (via -R). Special characters of the regex are escaped via a backspace character (that is, the $ char and the opening bracket of exec)

To see the context of found occurrences use the -C *num* argument of grep to see *num* lines around the found line:

```
grep --color=auto -C 2 -ER '\$_POST|\$_GET' .
```

You can also use -A(fter) and -B(efore) if you want to output a different number of lines before or after the line with the found occurrence of your pattern. You may also use the -n argument to get the line number of a found occurrence. If you want to get more fancy you can combine the find command with xargs and grep or use multiple grep commands connected via pipes, but that's better explained in tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -l` will just list the files that match; you can then pipe the output of that into another grep:

`grep -l -e "$_POST" -e "$_GET" * | grep -e "include" -e "include_once" -e "exec"`